# PHP Mysqli. Need to fetch data from table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, chromelogger

This is my code. I execute then nothing happen. Pls check my code

```
$id = trim(htmlentities($_REQUEST['id'],ENT_QUOTES)); //call the action from previous page

//fetch data
$stmt = $dbi->prepare("SELECT a.telco, a.no_siri, a.no_topup, a.amount, a.requestingAgentID, a.requestDateTime, a.isUsed, b.name FROM card_telco a LEFT JOIN agents b ON a.requestingAgentID = b.id WHERE id = ?"); //query
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id); //binding
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); //execute
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt); //store the result
$count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt); //execute rows
$stmt->bind_result($newTelco, $noSiri, $noTopup, $newAmount, $newRequestAgentID, $newRequestDateTime, $isUsing, $newName, $agendId); //binding new result
$stmt->execute() or die(mysqli_error()); //execute the statement
$stmt->store_result() //store new result
$stmt->fetch(); //fetch the data
$stmt->close(); //close the statement

ChromePhp::log('here'); //console
ChromePhp::log($newTelco, $noSiri); //console
```

Comment: any error that you got?

Comment: @Anant my localhost says page isnt working.

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param('i', $id); //binding`

Comment: @Anant same also :(

Comment: When i comment my code. Page working.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` on top of your current page just after starting `<?php` and  check any error is coming or not. execute the code again

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_DK0mlA1iw9Q08yeVo5RF9XejA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try code from this link:-http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_DK0mlA1iw9SjRJMkdkVFVWck0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please check the code step by step.
First comment all the lines then remove the comments from each line.
In which line has error it will display.
Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got it!! My query is wrong.

SELECT a.id, a.telco, a.no_siri, a.no_topup, a.amount, a.requestingAgentID, a.requestDateTime, a.isUsed, b.name FROM card_telco a LEFT JOIN agents b ON a.requestingAgentID = b.id WHERE a.id = ?

This is my new query. Thanks for helping me